# Design advice Android image buttons

Tags: android

I'm working on cleaning up my application making it a little nicer to look at I thought it would be nice to use images on  my buttons instead of text. However after finding some images cropping them down to size and inserting them into my app, the images are very small and look awful.

The Code I've used for inserting the images is as follows

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/SMS"
```

Is there a way to make the images the full size of the button? or maybe someone has a nicer way of doing the entire thing?

[image: My Application buttons]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Using the attribute `android:src` in `ImageButton` rather than `Button` will fix your problem. but then you need to clean up your code from `Button` to `ImageButton`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that any compound Drawable (drawableTop/Bottom etc.) used in a View will not be scaled. You could at least set the image as a background to the Button to fill it, like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/yourImageHere"
```

But prepare for a bad scaled image.

The best option is to use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) or [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) with a `OnClickListener`, where some scaling options are available. Like `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

Answer (score 0):

Using `ImageView` will solve your problem. It's a better option and you can perform the click event via `OnClickListener` and later you can scale with attributes given.